# How do you remove a epub book margin for kobo?

Tags: kobo

Sometimes when I download books in pdf and convert them to epub, the text for the book is very bunched. How would I remove the margin for my epub book? I use a kobo to read my books, and it’s annoying to read bunched-up letters!

Comment: Is the page margin the issue (what your title implies), or is it that there aren’t spaces between letters (what your question implies)?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Thomas a good program for converting pdf's to a reader is [k2pdfopt](https://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/) it is it's purpose

it is available for all operating systems and free :)

see if you have better results with that. good luck

[image]